# Can't SSH (or generally access) server over Wi-FI

Tags: ssh, wireless-networking, raspbian

When trying to ssh or ping my Raspberry Pi server on my LAN I get a "No route to host":

```
$ ping 192.168.50.249
                                                                                                         SIGINT(2) ↵  10146  16:43:15
PING 192.168.50.249 (192.168.50.249): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
```

This isn't an issue over ethernet and I can connect successfully.

The netstat command *looks* okay

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.50.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Port 22 is listening:

```
$ netstat -lpn | grep :22
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

And it looks like my firewall is appropriately configured:

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep 22
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The above commands are generally for ssh but I also can't ping.

I have an ASUS router and checked to see if AP Isolation is off - which it is.

The server itself can ping outside connections over Wi-Fi:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=26.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=18.8 ms
```

My best guess is the router is blocking connections but I can't find anything on there that would suggest so.

As a last resort, I've also tried reinstalling the OS but I'm getting the same issues.

Interestingly, I can access my server over Wi-Fi if the server itself is connected via ethernet.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

**Edit**

A network scan on the server seems to only detect devices that are connected via ethernet

```
$ arp -a
? (192.168.50.1) at a0:36:bc:14:75:f0 [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.50.203) at 00:1c:2b:52:a2:0d [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.50.10) at 70:85:c2:d3:25:ec [ether] on wlan0
```

Comment: Do you detect others devices with a network scan?

Comment: @JoelCrypto 
`$ arp -a
? (192.168.50.1) at a0:36:bc:14:75:f0 [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.50.203) at 00:1c:2b:52:a2:0d [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.50.10) at 70:85:c2:d3:25:ec [ether] on wlan0`

It seems to only detect devices that are connected via ethernet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what the actual issue was but I resorted to backing up router settings, factory resetting it and testing - it worked.

I then restored the settings and it still worked so couldn't pinpoint the problem. Either way, the problem is solved now